# Plugin for custom field?

Tags: wordpress

This plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/no-external-links/

I’m using a custom field.

`<?php $values = get_post_custom_values("imgurl"); echo $values[0]; ?>`

The plugin does not mask this my custom field. How do I mask this link?

**What code should I add to the function file? thanks**

```
// You will have to add just a line in a theme code where you output custom field data.
// To add same preprocessing for data as for comment text, use
$metadata = apply_filters(‘comment_text’, $metadata);

// For example, if you use some kind of metadata, it should look like this:
$metadata = get_post_meta($id, ‘MetaTagName’, true); // get data from wordpress database
$metadata = apply_filters(‘comment_text’, $metadata); // add this line of code for preprocessing field value
echo $metadata; //output preprocessed field value

// Use “the_content” instead of “comment_text” if you want to use the same masking policy as for post text. https://www.ozgurbilgi.net
```

Comment: I saw that you had already posted this in the support forum for the plugin. That's probably the best place to get the answer, as most of us probably aren't familiar with the plugin. Also, in that code snippet, they are using fancy quotes. Those will create errors.

Comment: A code needs to be added to the function file, but I couldn't find it. thanks for help.

Comment: the `functions.php` file is in your theme folder.

Comment: Yes I know that. What should be "custom field" code for the plugin? custom field "imgurl"   How do I mask this link? thanks

Comment: I'm guessing based on that example, you would use the second version. `$metadata = get_post_meta( $id, $values[0], true ); $metadata = apply_filters( 'the_content', $metadata); echo $metadata;`

Comment: my custom field "imgurl". Where should "imgurl" be added in this code? thanks

Comment: If `imgurl` is a `meta_name`, then it goes where I put `$values[0]`. But I have no idea what your database looks like, or what the data that comes from that meta value is. That is important information.

Comment: for example imgurl output = site.com/img133.html I want the plugin to mask this link.? thanks